# Easier way to move files up a level?

Tags: folder

I am trying to flatten the file structure we have on SharePoint. Is there an OOTB but non manual way to move the contents of a folder up a level?
I'd rather not download the contents of the folder, and then upload it all at again to a higher level. 
For some reason I cannot open the SP library in Explorer and adding to Trusted Sites doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Sharepoint in Internet Explorer. For whatever reason, the Open with Explorer option doesn't work with non-Microsoft browsers.
2. Library -> Open with Explorer
3. Drag files/folders across.

Answer (score 1):

If Open in Explorer does not work, try to use Content and Structure in Site settings

Comment: I can expand the folder tree but nothing appears inside any of the folders - it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That sounds like the error you get when you have a corrupt file or list/library. Are all folders empty or just the one you're trying to move?

Comment: all folders have content

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the view to **Show all items without folders**.  That won't technically move them out of one folder to its parent, but the effect might still be what you are looking for.

I've also used this concept paired with **Column default value settings** to make a view for each folder.

Regarding your issue with ExplorerView.  Ensure you are using IE.  I have several users that "accidently" get Chrome set as default browser, then Open in Explorer doesn't work.