# Move files into sub-folders in Library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, library, out-of-the-box, ootb

I have been trying to find a way for this one but haven't been able to. It may be right under my nose, so here it goes.

We have a Library with couple of folders, sub folders and files. I have been given access to folder and not the Library.

Now, I want to move files from the folder (to which I have access to) into its subfolders. I was able to use the `Open with Explorer` option to move the files but I was unable to find any link/button which does this from web page itself like a "Move file" or "Copy file". Is there any such option present?

Also, will the option `Open with Explorer` work in case I access the folder from Ubuntu or Mac?

From the questions [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/60559/20540) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/82950/20540) I figured out that I can go to `Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Administration > Content and Structure` to reorganize my Library. But as I have been given access to folder only I cannot see `Site Settings` link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the URL of the destination folder from the address bar.  Navigate to where you see your document in the library.  Either from the pulldown or by selecting the document and choosing **Send To** from the ribbon.  Select **Other Location** and paste your destination.  Sorry it is only one document at a time.

Comment: Notes: This copies the document, not move it. Version history is not retained on the copy.

Answer (score 4):

http://truapps.portalfront.com/how-to-copy-and-move-files-between-sharepoint-document-libraries-and-folders.html

Select the Library tab > choose the > 'Open with Explorer' tab and it will allow you to easily move files to folders, copy/paste, etc. Provides the same functionality windows explorer allows.

*requires Windows OS and 32 bit browser

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that I tried Open with Explorer option, I was looking for option via Web.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps by Steps method How to Move Files Between SharePoint Document Libraries**

1. In a document library, hover the mouse pointer over the document you want to move. A check box appears on the left and a list arrow on the right. click the Send To button. Select Other Location. The Copy dialog box appears. Type the destination or paste the URL, and then make sure you’re sending the document to the right place.
2. Next you can modify the document settings. You can rename the document or add “_copy” to the end of the file name, select whether to prompt the author to send updates when the document is checked in, and decide whether to create an alert when changes are made to the source document. When the copying is complete, click Done.

Answer (score 0):

Citing the same link Haydela used:
http://truapps.portalfront.com/how-to-copy-and-move-files-between-sharepoint-document-libraries-and-folders.html#copy-using-drag-and-drop

If you are running SharePoint 2013 or Offie365, then you can drag/drop to move files (but not folders, it seems).  The trick here is that you can't drag from just anywhere.  After selecting the files you want to move, you should drag from the "share" icon that appears to the right of the file-name (when the mouse point is in that position).  Drag from there and you should see a file (or stack-of-files) icon tracking the mouse pointer.  Drop it on the folder you want to move the files to (which can include one of the "breadcrumb" folder names just above the contents of the folder you're in.

This approach is much more convenient than using the "Move to" option (from a file's popup menu or the SharePoint toolbar) since that method forces you to navigate from the root of the library to the destination folder, which can be a pain if it's many folders down from the root.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when I follow the instructions posted by Robert Lindgren and Edward Martinez, above, I get an error message stating tha:

> The URL is too long.

All I am trying to do is clean up a shared document folder with files from 2015, 2016, 2017 and 2018.

I made a folder for each year and want to place appropriate files in each folder so the list of docs is not so long.

There's got to be an easier way.  Appreciate any feedback.

Thanks.